# Detect a new item and send an email

Tags: designer-workflow

I am using the sharepoint 2007 designer workflow to create the following rule:

> If and item in the list is created, sends a mail.

When I work with a library I check for the version field (if version = 1.0 sends an email). But how can I do this in lists?

tried: `if(Created Date=Modified Date)` without luck

What should i check/compare?

> [update #1] The list I am using is a Survey list... looks like a basic
> list has the version, but the survey did not
>
> [update #2]
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/05e100d2-4bd0-40ea-8354-c8628cb06724/trigger-a-workflow-when-a-survey-is-created : (

Answer (score 1):

I  have recently solved similar problem , just send an email to a person when new item is added. but unfortunately that was a list, not survey list. but the reason I tried to contribute is, I used another approach. I am not sure if this is available in sp 2007 , survey list. if available then you might try.
I used, workflow, condition- if created ( date ) between today -- to after 10-20 years, 
then action: send email... this is how it is generating email..to user. might be useful , use all these option available in sp 2007 , survey. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint Designer select the list you want to add the workflow to.

1. Click on "List Worklfow" on the ribbon
2. Provide a Name for your workflow and an optional Description
3. In the workflow designer setup your workflow:

   a. Add Action "send email"

   b. Specify the email parameters, you can use Lookups to search for values related to the item you have added. For instance in the field to you can select a Sharepoint Group or even the user who created the current item.

   c. In the body field you can insert values like Title etc by clicking on add or change lookup

   d. Add more actions as needed
4. Click on Workflow Settings in the Ribbon.
5. Untick Allow this workflow to be started manually and enable on created.
6. Save the workflow by clicking the save button in the ribbon
7. Publish the workflow by clicking the publish button in the ribbon

Workflow should now be activated for that List.

Comment: i tried that too, without luck. Just updated the topic, found the survey list is way different than basic list (as in my point of view)

Comment: Kart, I am using sharepoint 2007... maybe this works in 2010, but i have done the exact same thing you described and it did not work in 2007

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/05e100d2-4bd0-40ea-8354-c8628cb06724/trigger-a-workflow-when-a-survey-is-created :(

Comment: Then you can try with SharePoint List event receivers. http://www.walisystems.com/articles/sps/moss-surveys/eventhandler/writing-an-event-handler-for-a-survey.htm

Comment: I can't use VS : ( but I am really thankful for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use VS, you certainly can fire a workflow via Javascript.  You can create your own custom [PreSaveAction](http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/28/validation-on-sharepoint-forms-part-four/) on the New Form.  To edit the New Form, use the [ToolPaneView](http://www.spjeff.com/2010/05/12/howto-append-toolpaneview2-to-edit-aspx-forms-new-edit-display/) trick on the form.

Here's a [great project](https://spservices.codeplex.com) that will allow you to [fire that workflow easily](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow&referringTitle=Workflow).

Read over the documentation on how to get SPServices set up and you'll have this solved in no time.

Comment: thx, will try...

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you I've tried a number of times to fire workflows from Surveys in SP2007 - even going so far a few years ago to contact Microsoft. I spent days building a complex workflow, and couldn't for the life of me get it to run. Someone from Microsoft confided at that time that for SP2007 - the Survey Module just doesn't include the ability to run workflows. The options are all there, but it just doesn't work.

To save my work - I created a second list as a custom simple list- with the answers to the survey, and I created a simple JavaScript that sends the answers as an array when the survey is finished, and populates the items in the new list.

Good luck.